# Low results after half of dataset in keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to make a neural network (using keras, sklearn, tensorflow)  to predict (n+1)-th value for given dataset (1 dismension array). So for example if i have a list [2,3,12,1,5,3] as an input i want to get a [2,3,12,1,5,3,x] as an output.

Here are my real samples and predictions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwpjD.png

I am not really satisfied with this results, after half of samples my predictions became almost constant function. Can someone help me to understand what is a cause of this 'constant anomally' after half of X.

Is that maybe because of :

- neural network structure
- small quantity of train samples ( 50-80)
- very diverse input dataset

Here are my setup:

```
    def compile_model(self):
        self.model.compile(
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),  # Optimizer
            loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
        )

    def fit_model(self, verbose=0):
        return self.model.fit(
            self.train_x[:int(len(self.train_x) * 0.66)],
            self.train_y[:int(len(self.train_x) * 0.66)],
            epochs=900,
            # steps_per_epoch=10,
            batch_size=10,
            verbose=verbose,
            validation_data=(self.train_y[int(len(self.train_x) * 0.66):],
                             self.train_x[int(len(self.train_x) * 0.66):])
        ).history
```

Structure:

```
  def setup_model(self):
        self.model.add(Dense(99, input_dim=1, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        self.model.add(Dense(256, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        self.model.add(Dense(90, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(Dense(45, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        self.model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        self.model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
```

Comment: Since you are trying to predict linear values, try to remove tanh activation from the last dense layer. That might help.

Comment: Why are you using tanh activation on your whole network? Are you aware of what consequences will it bring?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Well I have noticed that gives the smallest loss (mse). Well I had also implemented a local search to find some well combinations between activations and quantity of neurons on each layers. But seems that this one with tang is some kind better.

Comment: @Frightera Well, you want to change it to what? to Sigmoid?

Comment: Tanh and sigmoid leads to vanishing gradients, is not that activation that modern neural networks use.

Comment: @sqoshi I don't understand why you are insisting to use non-linear activations when making regression with Keras. With last dense's tanh you are just squeezing your output, it should have been a linear dense like Dense(1)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I would be really grateful if only you could tell me some example activations that should I use.

Comment: Simple, the ReLU and variations are what modern NNs use.

Comment: @Frightera Hmm so you suggest me to avoid things like tanh and change them all to things like relu, selu ? I am not really into ML/ DL and my knowledge here is not really wide :D ( sorry for stupid questions)

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED: I was doing prediction using simple f(x)=y dependency, so my model was learning only basing on a day index for example f(0)=123,f(1)=124. The thing i did was to divide list [2,3,12,1,5,3] into parts: x=[2,3,12],y=1 ; x=[3,12,1],y=5 ; x=[12,1,5],y=3; and now my neural network learning basing on few samples which carried me to perfect results with less samples my predict x if i want know n+1 value of list is x=[1,5,3] and from this few days i could get a lot better results.